# Should an extended version of a Paper contain the existing Paper?

Tags: journals, conference, extended-paper, publications

I have a conference paper published in A and now they have invited me to submit an extended version of the Paper in a Journal. Due to page limitations, I had a lot of work that I couldn't present at the conference.

Hence, can I include the excess work ONLY in the Journal and cite the conference paper **OR** do I need to include the entire conference paper and then the extra work?

Kindly help. As you may understand, I am entirely new to this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the paper is published it is part of the public record. Cite it as you would a paper by any other author who's work you were extending. Include only the new work, referencing the earlier work.

You will, of course, need to quote or paraphrase some things in the new work, but cite them, just as for any other paper.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks

Comment: Note that this include figures as well. In many cases one would basically include everything, in practice. I guess the exact way is field and journal dependent. The fact that you are invited might also help. Finally, the ms text should be cleverly written... Like passing a mini review of your conference paper. Graphs and plots might be crucial for the overall readability...